# How to prevent function return result declaratively?

Tags: dart

Assume such conditions:

- Some operation does not provide possibility of returning the result.
- This operation declared as callback
- Using typedef not recommended
- Some operation provide of returning the result.
- This operation declared as callback
- Using typedef not recommended

Assume such scenario:

```dart
void main() {
  executeVoidOperation(methodNonVoid);  // Must throw if method void?
  executeNonVoidOperation(methodVoid);  // Must throw if method non-void?
}

int methodNonVoid() {
  return 0;
}

void methodVoid() {
}

void executeVoidOperation(void operation()) {
  operation(); // Must throw if method non-void?
}

void executeNonVoidOperation(dynamic operation()) {
  var result = operation(); // Must throw if method void?
  print(result); // Result of void operation? (if such passed as argument)
}
```

Displayed results:

```
null
```

Questions (where I wrong?):

- `Null` is object. From where this `null` appeared (`as result`) if `void` function cannot return result (even `null`)?
- Functions with different return types in Dart assumed as the same (not conflicting) types?
- How in Dart called this function transformations?

Answer (score 2):

`executeNonVoidOperation(methodVoid);` works because the callback is defined as `dynamic operation()`. `dynamic` can be anything, including `void`. It's the same as if you just don't specify a type.

The `null` value stems from a simple rule in Dart. Quoted from the [Dart Language Tour](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#ch02-functions-return-values):

> All functions return a value. If no return value is specified, the statement return null; is implicitly appended to the function body.

That means that every `void` method always returns null. If you try to return something else, you'll get a runtime error (in checked mode).

`executeVoidOperation(methodNonVoid);` is a bit more tricky - I'd expect it to throw a runtime error, but it seems the callback is treated as `dynamic operation()` instead of `void operation()`. Dart Editor's analyzer seems to think that, too. This may be either a bug or a design choice by the Dart team.

Comment: Thank for explanation. But words like `design choice by the Dart team` for me do not sound as clear as opposed to full specification or proposal (if this feature is not completed). All possible behaviors must be specified.

Comment: By "design choice" I meant "says so in the specification (designed by the Dart team)". It's a long, technical document which I didn't want to read yet. But here it is, if you want to look into it: http://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/latest/dart-language-specification.html